# pressing on button it should display TextInput fields

Tags: react-native, textinput

i want the output like, whenever i press on 'edit' it should display some textInput fields. How can i write function for that? and how to store those textInput values in variable? is that possible to create a function which has TextInput fiellds and calling by pressing on 'edit'?  thank you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import Button from 'react-native-button'
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux'
import Home from './Home'

export class Bp extends Component{
     state={
            responseBody:""
        }

     _onPressButtonPOST(){
          return fetch("URL", {
            method: "POST",
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             },
            body: JSON.stringify({entryDate:"2/27/2017 11:11 AM",systol:"900"})
        })

        .then((responseData) => {
           this.setState({
                         responseBody: JSON.stringify({entryDate:"2/27/2017 11:11 AM",systol:"900"})
                      })
          })
        .done();
    }
render(){
        return(
            <View>
         <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text> Edit </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButtonPOST.bind(this)} >
          <Text> Show </Text>
                           {this._renderBody(this.state.responseBody)}
                        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
            );
    }

     _renderBody(responseBody){
          if(responseBody){
           var parsedBody=JSON.parse(responseBody);
            return (<View>
                     <Text>{parsedBody.entryDate}</Text>
                     <Text>systolic:{parsedBody.systolic}</Text>
                     <Text>diastolic:{parsedBody.diastolic}</Text>
                     <Text>pulseRate:{parsedBody.pulseRate}</Text>
                 </View>);
           }
               }
}

module.exports = Bp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you want a text field.

```
 <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({textinput: text})}
        value={textinput}
      />
```

This is a TextInput, everytime you change the value (text entered in it) value will be saved in the state with key 'textinput'

Next step :

```
this.state={
textinput: '',
shouldShow: false
}

<TouchableOpacity
 onPress={()=>{ this.setState({ shouldShow: !this.state.shouldShow })}}
><Text>Edit</Text></TouchableOpacity>
{this.state.shouldShow ? <TextInput
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({textinput: text})}
            value={textinput}
          /> : null}
```

TextInput is being rendered conditionally.it will be rendered only if the value of `shouldShow` in the state, is `true`.

value of `shouldShow` by default is `false` , when user clicks on Edit button, value in the state will be changed, and `TextInput` will be shown.

also the entered value in the `TextInput` is saved at state, you can easily access it via `this.state.textinput`

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is helpful. and how can i assign textInput value to 'systol' in the above code?

Comment: well, instead of systol just use >>> body: JSON.stringify({entryDate:"2/27/2017 11:11 AM",systol:this.state.textinput})

Comment: can i use multiple textInputs?

Comment: you want to merge Multiple textinput's values?

Comment: like systol, i wanna read other values too so can use multiple textInputs?

Comment: @PrasannaKumarKulkarni of course. just use different keys in the state, like textinput1 textinput2 textinput3, actually its better to give them better names.

Comment: @PrasannaKumarKulkarni I'd suggest you read about basic javascript programming, then read the reactjs's tutorials and finally start working with react-native. otherwise it would take you a long time to learn the basics.

Comment: Thank you @ataomega.. i studied but i dont remember. that iss why i am practicing.

Comment: and also in the above code, values are communicating with given url. i mean data is not storing in web services(url)